# Printing PDF from overleaf with comments included

Tags: overleaf, printing, comments

I would like to print my PDF from overleaf, but have it include the comments made using overleaf editor (The ones where you *select a piece of text-> add comment*). Is it possible to somehow do this?

Kind regards,
Chris

Comment: Welcome :) // Please provide your code, via the Edit button. We'd like to know your preamble. You can reduce the document text itself to only the relevant part, which shows your problem. We like to copy&run your code, if necessary ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you refer to these kind of  comments:

[image]

They seem to be a feature of the overleaf editor, and from what I know they are not in any way added to the source file nor to the PDF output (but I can be wrong, never used it). It's my understanding that they are used for comments among several editors of the same project.

If you want comments displayable in the PDF file, you should use a LaTeX package, see for example https://www.overleaf.com/blog/619-tip-of-the-week-add-inline-or-margin-comments-to-your-pdf

Comment: I really liked the todo package in the link, thanks! However, in general if one uses templates which don't have generous margins (which is usually the case with journal article classes), this doesn't seem to work well, as there's not enough margin for such comments. Therefore I'm shamelessly plugging my own solution in case anyone's interested: https://git.sr.ht/~tpapastylianou/a-tidy-latex-project-template/tree/main/item/dependencies/macros/mymacros.tex (note that the color definitions are defined elsewhere; have a look at the `include` folder).

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is a full page screenshot. Chrome has a few of these extensions; here is one (GoFullPage): https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl

This extension will produce image or PDF files that includes Overleaf comments on the side (as in the screenshot by Rmano). A problem arises if there are too many comments in a particular area. The comments might not align. In this scenario, when editing, Overleaf moves comments a bit when a specific comment is clicked to better align; not possible in a static PDF.